# SQL Show 2 rows in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a query like this.

[image: Query]

After executing I'm getting following result.

[image: Result]

What I want to do is for each Invoice No I want to show 'Amount' as a CashAmt and ChequeAmt
in a one row. Currently there is 2 records for cash and cheque.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to `pivot` your results.  You can do this with `group by`, `max` and `case`:

```
select mdr.invoiceno, mdr.invoicedate, mdr.customerid, mdr.netamount, cus.name,
    max(case when pt.Name = 'Cash' then pay.amount end) CashAmt,
    max(case when pt.Name = 'Cheque' then pay.amount end) ChequeAmt
from customer cus
    ....
group by mdr.invoiceno, mdr.invoicedate, mdr.customerid, mdr.netamount, cus.name
order by mdr.invoiceno
```

Comment: Can I know why we need to use as max(case ...? why we need to consider MAX?

Comment: @Tom, you are trying to combine 2 rows into 1 (a form of `pivoting`).  One way to do this is to use the `max` aggregate with `group by` to group those results together.